# ASP.NET webform some entities not work after hosted

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I have an web application that works fine in my local machine. But when I upload my webform application to our host some entities not work!!

For example, I have Users and Persons classes. These two tables are same but for login Users are work and Persons not work!!!

Here is some my code:

For Users:

```
 public User GetUserByUserName(string userName)
        {
            return context.Users.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == userName);
        }
```

And for Persons:(this method return null, and context.Persons.Count() returns Zero !!!)

```
public Person GetPersonByUserName(string username)
        {
           return context.Persons.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == username);

        }
```

> In additional, when I use *sqldatasources* all thing works fine in this page

Comment: Do you have any Users or Persons in the hosted database?

Comment: @DavidG Yes I have, another thing is that I can's add more persons!! context.Persons.Add(p); returns 0 and not save new person!!!

Comment: After you do the `Add`, did you remember to do `SaveChanges` on your context?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I said that all things works fine in my local machine! All methods are the same.

Comment: Are you using the same database server on local machine as you are when hosted, or a local database server?

Comment: @John Thanks its solved! I don't know how, but I have SQL server 2008 and 2012 on my server and 2 db created on both of them and some of my data stored in 2008 db and other saved in 2012, now I'm so surprised :-o